# How do I push an object to a JSON file with javascript?

Tags: node.js, json, react-native, fs, react-native-fs

So, I have my JSON file:

```
{
   HomeWork: []
}
```

And I want to push an object:
`{Title: T, Due: D, Description: Desc}` To the JSON file, How should I do that? I am using this right now:

```
async function AddWork(obj) {
workData.HomeWork.push(obj);
//RNFS.writeFile('../../json/work.js', JSON.stringify(workData));
}
```

I tried whit the RNFS line, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that, **there is no edit mode !** so be careful .

If you read it and modify it , you are doing it locally, so you need override the file you are working on.

you need to read it using [Read File in fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs/v/1.2.0#promise-readfilepath--encoding) and then after you do the modification you need to [Write it on the top of the file you are working with](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs/v/1.2.0#promise-writefilefilepath-contents--encoding-options)

I hope it helps <3

Comment: Thanks but how should i do it?, I am new to  working with files.

Comment: as you mention rnfs i gave you the docs for that, i personally recommend using RNFetchBlob instead of RNFS! 
read the documentation its clear , if you got any problem write here i will help you. this link can help you https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#writefilepathstring-contentstring--array-encodingstring-appendbooleanpromise

Comment: I am really sorry, i tried to read the docs but i suck at it. I really don't have any idea on how to do it. :(